# Azure Hub IoT to Azure Function Pricing

Tags: azure, events, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

I'm making a comparison between different Cloud vendors for IoT solutions.
I'm now on Azure IoT Hub, which will ingest data from IoT devices (we want only to send from devices to cloud, say through MQTT, and not receive anything back). My aim is to pass these data to an Azure Function, execute some computation, and save them in some DB (e.g.CosmosDB). Here my doubts:

1. Which MQTT messages Do I have to consider for the billing? (only those with telemetry or which others?)
2. I saw that there is the possibility of going from Hub IoT to Azure Function with a built-in endpoint. Is it free? I'm afraid of some hidden costs, like those of Event Hubs or the built-in endpoint.
3. The sending of data from IoT Hub to Azure Function is considered as a normal "cloud-to-device" messages (and consequently they're billed), or are they free? For example IoT Hub ingest 10 messages (<4KB) and forward them to Functions. Do I pay them as 10 messages or 20 messages?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't the right forum for billing questions and I suspect your question might end up getting deleted here. I'd recommend asking this type of question on Microsoft Q&A  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/azure-iot.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Which MQTT messages - You have to consider the below list of messages for Azure IoTHub Billing, they are

- Device to Cloud
- Cloud to Device

  - Method execution
  - Jobs

Detailed break up of billing information by each operation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-pricing#charges-per-operation

---

2. Nothing free in the cloud :)

Data read from IoTHub to any other service attracts the regular data transfer cost. Refer to the below link

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/bandwidth/

---

3. All the pricing information detailed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-pricing is specific to Azure IoTHub for D2C & C2D. Any data egress from IoTHub to other Azure Services is as per the regular data transfer charges.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/bandwidth/